Docsy/Hugo -- ERROR POSTCSS: failed to transform "/scss/main.css" (text/css): Error: Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
I'm new to Docsy (and Hugo). Trying to build the example site for the very first time. I'm getting this error:

hugo v0.134.2-1c74abd26070b0c12849550c974a9f3f1e7afb06+extended linux/amd64 BuildDate=2024-09-10T10:46:33Z VendorInfo=gohugoio
ERROR POSTCSS: failed to transform "/scss/main.css" (text/css): Error: Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
Require stack:
- /workspace/postcss.config.js
 (@/workspace/postcss.config.js)

at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/postcss-cli/node_modules/postcss-load-config/src/plugins.js:28:11)

The strange thing is that autoprefixer package is installed in the same location as the postcss-cli package, which is presumably trying to call it:

npm -g list
/usr/local/lib
autoprefixer@10.4.20
postcss-cli@11.0.0
postcss@8.4.47


npx autoprefixer --version
autoprefixer 10.4.20

Any clues much appreciated.
thanks,
